# Ransomware attack

Tags: virus, bootable-media, ransomware

My desktop has been hijacked by ransomware. They won't let me reach the login screen. Even tried safe mode, but I can't get past the virus. I have a bootable linux mint USB, can I boot it on the PC and scan for viruses? If so, how? The data has not been encrypted, I am lucky enough.

Comment: You can try to do virus scan using ClamAV which should be available on linux distro. Your best bet is to save all your files and data and wipe the HDD to be somewhat sure that the virus are all gone.

Comment: In regards to booting the system with another OS, many antivirus vendors provide a free rescue CD which you can download in .iso form and burn to a CD - see the list of [live cds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_cd) listed at the link provided by Arjan. The free live CDs are usually based on Linux. You might need to try several to rid the system of malware. You can also create such a CD with [Spybot](https://www.safer-networking.org/features/bootcd/). Are you sure no files are encrypted, though, if you can't log in? Ransomware often encrypts pictures, Microsoft Office documents, etc.

Comment: I booted from the live USB and navigated around my HDD and opened some files and videos and pics, all looked normal. So I concluded that the ransomware had not encrypted them. But I can't backup them, my desktop IS my backup pc. I have no other place to backup.